# Asterisk: Where asterisk stores it's data

Tags: asterisk, sip

I'm finding the place that Asterisk stores it's data.
For example: Command "Show sip peers" will return all sip peers with their IP address and status. I wonder where they were stored in the drive.

I didn't install MySQL or any DB

Comment: This is very much OT for StackOverflow. Try the [asterisk-users mailing list or IRC channel](http://www.asterisk.org/community/discuss).

Answer (score 1):

SIP registrations are stored in the astdb mentioned before. From I believe asterisk 11 this astdb is an sqlite database.

Answer (score 0):

Sip peers info stored in memory

Same as most of internal states.

There is astdb which stored in db4 in /var/lib/asterisk/astdb, but very few data stored in db.

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk version upto 1.8 the data stored as **Berkeley DB**. From version 10 onward Asterisk uses built in **Sqlite** database.